# Setting up Cloudberry Backup for Linux for OracleCloud

Tags: linux, cloudberry, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I'm trying to add an account for OracleCloud, and I'm not sure I'm setting some of the required parameters correctly.  My current command looks like this:
cbb addAccount -st OracleCloud -d OracleCloud -un "storage-a229571:" -kv no -c oracle-data-storagea-1 -ep https://a229571.storage.oraclecloud.com/v1/storage-a229571 -reg "US Commercial 2 us2" -ak https://us2.storage.oraclecloud.com/auth/v1.0

I get this response when I run it:
Can't validate account
Code: get openstack token v1. Message: Can't get token
Code: get openstack token v1. Message: Can't get token
Code: Can't get work url. Message: Can't get work url

Has anyone been able to use Cloudberry Backup for Linux against the OracleCloud?

Answer (score 0):

This due to your -kv flag which you set to "no". You need 2 or 3, which guides Cloudberry Backup to use v2 or v3 Keystone version (consult your Oracle reps). Check this [page](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backupcmd_nix.aspx)

The below are full list of flags you may want to use:

```
[root@localhost]# cbb addAccount -d Display_Name -st OracleCloud -h
CloudBerry Backup Command Line Interface started
addAccount -d Display_Name -st OracleCloud <-un UserName> <-ak ApiKey> <-c  BackupContainer> <-ep Endpoint>  [-useInternalUrl yes/no(default)] [-reg Region] [-bp BackupPrefix] <-kv no> | <-kv 2 <-tn TenantName | -ti TenantID> > | <-kv 3 [-us < yes | no > <-pn project_name> | <-pi project_id>] <-dn DomainName | -di DomainID> >
     -d   Display_Name    : Display name.
     -un  UserName        : User name.
     -ak  ApiKey          : Api key.
     -reg Region          : Region. Optional.
     -c   BackupContainer : Backup container.
     -ep  Endpoint        : Auth endpoint.
     -bp  BackupPrefix    : Backup prefix to differentiate between backups from different computers. Optional, by default is computer name.
     -kv  Keystone Version: Keystone version. Possible values 2, 3, no.
     -pn  project_name    : Project name. Use only with keystone version 3.
     -pi  project_id      : Project id. Use only with keystone version 3.
     -tn  TenantName      : Tenant name. Use only with keystone version 2.
     -ti  TenantID        : Tenant id. Use only with keystone version 2.
     -us  Use_scope       : Use scope. Use only with keystone version 3. Possilble values yes, no.
     -dn  DomainName      : Domain name. Use only with keystone version 3.
     -dn  DomainID        : Domain id. Use only with keystone version 3.
     -useInternalUrl      : use internal url. Optional, by default is no. Possilble values yes, no.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally had time to work on this again.  This is what I figured out:

```
cbb addAccount -st OracleCloud \
-d <Some Name> \
-un "storage-<identity domain>:<Oracle Cloud User Name>" \
-ak "<Password for -un>" \
-c "<An existing Container>" \
-ep <Authentication Endpoint> \
-kv no

-ep is usually https://<data center>.storage.oraclecloud.com/auth/v1.0
-reg is optional, and I could not get cbb to work if I included it
```